# eclipse/PHP : The import Tracy\Debugger cannot be resolved

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

I'm using Eclipse to develop a server written in PHP
I am now using tracy https://tracy.nette.org/ to retrieve debug information. It works and it's great to get cold and rich informations

```
<?php
require_once 'tracy.phar';

use Tracy\Debugger;
Debugger::enable(Debugger::DETECT, __DIR__ . '/mylog');
```

I got red alerts from Eclipse: **The import Tracy\Debugger cannot be resolved**

Any clue ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found !

Project Properties > Include Path to external PHAR

Don't forget to clean the project, to check build automatically
and then the include Phar libray is taken into consideration, at least...

Comment: Second thought : use Netbeans instead of Eclipse